# Crashlytics/Fabric beta distribution with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

How do I generate beta builds with Crashlytics/Fabric under Xcode 8? Is it still possible to use `Automatically manage signing` or do I have to do it manually as in Xcode 7 and before?

Currently a tester gets `Download problem detected` and I'm using `Automatically manage signing`, but I don't know if that's related...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use automatic signing.

You have to select the proper adhoc certificate/provisioning profile and create a specific build that will be distributed using Crashlytics.

I guess that the downloading problem is caused by the missing device ID in the certificate.